# Installing Ubuntu server after Ubuntu desktop

Tags: server

I have Ubuntu desktop.  How do I install LAMP to run on it or can I?

Answer (score 0):

You can install server packages on top of the desktop version, using `tasksel` like you would during a server installation.

`sudo apt-get install tasksel`

You can then run `tasksel` with `sudo` and select "LAMP Server" as you would with a server version installation.

That is the easiest way to setup a LAMP server on Desktop without installing all the packages by hand.